# How to wipe user data in emulator using terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

Im installing apks and starting my emulator in the terminal. My problem is Idk how to do the `Wipe user data` when starting the emulator. I read something in the android site to use -wipe-data command but it doesn't give an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emulator -avd yourEmulatorName -wipe-data
```

try this